# what loop does this break break?

Tags: python

```
n = int(input('Input an integer: '))
modn = abs(n)
power = 2
while power < 6:
    root = 0
    while root ** power < modn :
        root = root + 1
    if root ** power == modn and n < 0 :
        root = -root
        print(root, 'raised to', power, 'is', n)

        break #<---------(this break) 
    elif root ** power == modn and n > 0 :
        print(root, 'raised to', power, 'is', n)
        break
    else : power = power + 1

    if power == 6 :
        print('No values of power and root exist for this input.')
```

I wrote down this code for the finger exercise in Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python, by John Guttag, and so far it works good.
My question is which loop is being stopped by the first break, is it the `while power < 6`
or `while root ** power < modn :`. My guess is the first while loop but shouldn't it be the second?

Answer (score 1):

It is the first while loop.

The second while loop only consists of

```
while root ** power < modn :
    root = root + 1
```

It doesn't contain a break statement.

Comment: Oh, so the break statement must be under the while loop itself, or in technical language, nested in the while loop? (I'm very new to programming so not sure of the terminologies etc)

Answer (score 1):

I'll be the first loop because of the indentation of your code, you actually do the break outside of the loop i think what you are trying to achieve is

```
n = int(input('Input an integer: '))
modn = abs(n)
power = 2
while power < 6:
    root = 0
    while root ** power < modn :
        root = root + 1
        if root ** power == modn and n < 0 :
            root = -root
            print(root, 'raised to', power, 'is', n)

            break #<---------(this break) 
        elif root ** power == modn and n > 0 :
            print(root, 'raised to', power, 'is', n)
            break
        else : power = power + 1

if power == 6 :
    print('No values of power and root exist for this input.')
```

Comment: The OPs original code is correct and works as expected. Changing the indentation in the way you have done breaks it. Please test your code properly before posting.

Comment: I didn't test the code, but i explained why it's not breaking the second loop as that's what he asked for